# Check a rows TTL in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I have a table/column family which I am inserting rows that expire after a certain amount of time. Is it possible to then query the table to check which rows are going to expire soon (for diagnostic purposes, ie something like this:

```
select subject, ?ttl? from discussions;
```

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_ttl_t.html

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can do

```
select subject, TTL(subject) from discussions;
```

to return the remaining TTL in seconds for subject.

E.g.

```
> insert into discussions (uid, subject) VALUES (now(), 'hello') using ttl 100;
> select subject, TTL(subject) from discussions;

 subject | ttl(subject)
---------+--------------
   hello |           84
```

since I waited 16 seconds before running the select.

Comment: Excellent detailed but concise answer. Thanks!

Comment: this is not working for me : somebody else had the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201000/check-current-ttl-on-collection-columns-in-cassandra

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps post a question detailing your exact scenario.